# How to query MMS sender and text from MMS database

Tags: android

In android, How can I query the name of the MMS sender and text of the MMS from MMS database?
For SMS, there are these 2 columns for that: Sms.PERSON_ID and Sms.Body.

But what is the equivalent columns in MMS Table?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the database at `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/smsmms.db`?

There isn't an MMS table in there. I'm not sure exactly how it's storing the data, but it's clearly not as straightforward as in the **SMS** table.

Could you provide more info on how you're getting the SMS data?